# pandas groupby dataframes, calculate diffs between consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Using pandas, I open some csv files in a loop and set the index to the `cycleID` column, except the `cycleID` column is not unique. See below:

```
for filename in all_files:
    abfdata = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    abfdata = abfdata.set_index("cycleID", drop=False)

for index, row in abfdata.iterrows():
    print(row['cycleID'], row['mean'])
```

This prints the 2 columns (`cycleID` and `mean`) of the dataframe I am interested in for further computations:

```
1 1.5020712104685252e-11
1 6.56683605063102e-12
2 1.3993315187144084e-11
2 -8.670502467042485e-13
3 7.0270625256163566e-12
3 9.509995221868016e-12
4 1.2901435995915644e-11
4 9.513106448422182e-12
```

The objective is to use the rows corresponding to the same `cycleID` and calculate the difference between the `mean` column values. So, if there are 8 rows in the table, the final array or list would store 4 values.

I want to make it scalable as well where there can be 3 or more rows with the same `cycleID`s. In that case, each `cycleID` could have 2 or more `mean` differences.

---

Update: Instead of creating a new ques about it, I thought I'd add here.
I used the diff and groupby approach as mentioned in the solution. It works great but I have this extra need to save one of the mean values (odd row or even row doesn't matter) in a new column and make that part of the new data frame as well. How do I do that?

Comment: So if there means A,B,C for cycle id 5(suppose) you want to calculate (A-B), (A-C), (B-C), right? And it is difference or absolute value of difference, I means does the neagtive sign matters?

Comment: B-A, C-B, D-C  and so on actually. @Epsi95

I updated my ques. I can print the select two columns now.

Comment: where does D come from? U mean B-A, C-B, C-A right?

Comment: Oh, I meant if there are 5 rows under one cycle ID then there will be 4 differences. And if there are 4 rows under the same cycleID then it would be 3 differences.

For instance with 4 rows in the table under same ID, we would store something like B-A, C-B, D-C. It's the difference between subsequent rows always.

In what you said it would only be B-A and C-B. @Epsi95

Comment: You don't need `.iterrrows()`, just do `.groupby('cycle_id')` then do some sort of calculation on the means. For example [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) calculate the difference between rows.  Please read the [pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html) on grouping, logical indexing etc.

Comment: @smci Could you share how this diff() approach can also do what I described in the Update section of the question above?

Comment: bit_by_bit: you just [edited the question to add a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66057929/revisions) which will obviously break some approaches (*'save one of the mean values in a new column, doesn't matter which'*). Better ask as a separate question. Also, for determinism, pick which row (e.g. "the first"). Anyway the answer to *"How do I add a new column to the output of an aggregate?"* is You can still use [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html), just pass a dictionary of functions. Or `transform()`, or manually.

Comment: Thanks @smci
Another question on matplotlip plotting. Could you share your thoughts on how this can be achieved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181074/hide-the-legend-items-in-matplotlib-with-value-0

Comment: bit_by_bit: Please don't do this. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181074/hide-the-legend-items-in-matplotlib-with-value-0) is not even a matplotlib question, it's about filtering in pandas, which ahs hundreds of existing duplicates, please read them. But also you need to fix all the issues with that question quick before it gets closed. Don't use comment discussions like this to solicit answers to other questions, please follow the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines and use accurate titles, then your questions will get attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`

```py
s2= df.groupby(['cycleID'])['mean'].diff()
s2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

output

```
1   -8.453876e-12
3   -1.486037e-11
5   2.482933e-12
7   -3.388330e-12
8   3.000000e-12
```

---

### UPDATE

```py
d = [[1, 1.5020712104685252e-11],
[1, 6.56683605063102e-12],
[2, 1.3993315187144084e-11],
[2, -8.670502467042485e-13],
[3, 7.0270625256163566e-12],
[3, 9.509995221868016e-12],
[4, 1.2901435995915644e-11],
[4, 9.513106448422182e-12]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['cycleID', 'mean'])



df2 = df.groupby(['cycleID']).diff().dropna().rename(columns={'mean': 'difference'})
df2['mean'] = df['mean'].iloc[df2.index]
```

```
       difference    mean
1   -8.453876e-12   6.566836e-12
3   -1.486037e-11   -8.670502e-13
5   2.482933e-12    9.509995e-12
7   -3.388330e-12   9.513106e-12
```

Comment: Here's what I understood. You group them by cycleID. apply a lambda filter that subtracts 2 subsequent cells in the mean column? what happens to the rest of the fields?

Further, drop any missing values i.e. likely the last row, if the shift is upwards while subtracting?

and then creates a new name for the modified dataframe

Comment: yes you are correct, first grouping by `cycleID`. Now for each froup suppose it is`A,B,C. Now I am shift the group by -1 i.e. (B,C, NA) and taking difference. Ir. (B-A, C-B, NA). Now I am removing the NA. So it becomes (B-A, C-B). Lastly I am making a miltiindex dataframe. That's it

Comment: You totally don't need that `apply(lambda ...)`, pandas has a [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) method on both dataframes and series. Just use it.

Comment: @Epsi95 I am lost between the 2 columns on the left.  What exactly are [1 2 3 4] and [0 2 4 6] ?

Comment: @smci I'll look into diff()

Comment: This question is a duplicate, there are [852 existing questions and answers on *\[pandas\] groupby diff*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+groupby+diff) and similar terms, the SO procedure is to pick the closest duplicate and close this question into it.

Comment: @ankitrana_ 1234 is the `cycleID` and 0246 are the row or index numbers

Comment: @smci lemme check

Comment: @Epsi95 Interesting. When I use the diff(), the column that is 0 2 4 6 changes to 1 3 5 7 (odd numbers) while the mean difference is the same (B-A format)

Comment: @ankitrana_ it is happending because I am shifting the left series and then subtraction. If you do the opposite you will get 1,3,5,7

Comment: @Epsi95 Sorry, did not follow. What do you mean by 'shifting the left series and then subtraction'. I thought it was the Bottom row minus the row above it. No?

Comment: @Epsi95 There is a slight new requirement. Could you highlight how that can be accommodated with what you suggested

Comment: check the answer bru!

Comment: Thanks, mate. That worked! Is there a quick inline fix maybe for this? @Epsi95

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181074/hide-the-legend-items-in-matplotlib-with-value-0